Does innate sorcery apply to every attack from storm sphere?
A player at my table is looking at the 5e-2024 sorcerer and the 4th-level Storm Sphere spell from the Elemental Evil Players Companion.
The spell provides a modest 2d6 AoE for the duration of its 1-minute concentration and also allows the caster to use a bonus action to attack within 60' for an additional 4d6 lightning per strike. All on its own, it is a pretty powerful 4th-level spell.
The new sorcerer has a 1st-level class feature called Innate Sorcery that, among other things, grants advantage on magical attack rolls for the next minute.
I have several questions about the interaction of these two things:

Does the advantage on attacks apply to every attack made by the Storm Sphere for the duration of Innate Sorcery, effectively granting ten bonus action advantaged attacks at the cost of only one spell slot?

Does the order of operations matter? For instance, if the caster activates Innate Sorcery the round after they cast Storm Sphere, do they get advantage on the Storm Sphere's attack rolls at all?

If the order of operations is the other way around--that is, if Innate Sorcery is activated one or more rounds before casting Storm Sphere--does the advantage last for the entire duration of Storm Sphere, or does advantage end when the Innate Sorcery ends?

Does the advantage apply to every spell attack for the duration? For instance, if in subsequent rounds the caster uses additional attack spells and cantrips, is every roll advantaged? For instance, does Scorching Ray, which requires separate rolls for every attack, receive advantage on every attack?


I'm interested in this question because it seems that with the activation of a single 1st-level class feature in combination with that spell, a 7th-level sorcerer can provide themselves 20-40 advantaged attack rolls in ten rounds, which seems excessive. Am I understanding the rules correctly?

It will grant advantage on those attacks, but they are unlikely to make ten of them and some of them will have advantage already
The rules for Innate Sorcery are:

As a Bonus Action, you can unleash that magic for 1 minute, during which you gain the following benefits:

The spell save DC of your Sorcerer spells increases by 1.
You have Advantage on the attack rolls of Sorcerer spells you cast.

You can use this feature twice, and you regain all expended uses of it when you finish a Long Rest.

It might be considered a little ambiguous, but my reading is that the benefits apply to attack rolls and saving throws made against the Sorcerer’s save DC during that minute, not that they apply only to rolls for spells cast during the minute. Certainly that’s how I’d rule it, for reasons that will likely become clear below.
Even so, as you say, they could just use it before casting storm sphere.
Storm sphere is a concentration spell which says, in part:

A 20-foot-radius sphere of whirling air springs into existence centered on a point you choose within range. The sphere remains for the spell’s duration.
[…]
Until the spell ends, you can use a bonus action on each of your turns to cause a bolt of lightning to leap from the center of the sphere toward one creature you choose within 60 feet of the center. Make a ranged spell attack. You have advantage on the attack roll if the target is in the sphere. On a hit, the target takes 4d6 lightning damage.

So there are several factors limiting how much of a problem this is. First, at least for the first turn or so, attacks are likely to be made against creatures within the sphere, so they already have advantage and gain no benefit from Innate Sorcery.
Second, the spell is unlikely to last a full ten rounds: it’s a concentration spell, so opponents who realise where the big ball of nasty lightning and storm is coming from are likely to target the caster to disrupt that. (They might not succeed, but that’s potentially drawing a lot of attention and damage on to themselves.) Plus ten rounds is a long combat, even at high levels - most end after only three or four.
So while you are reading the rules correctly, I don’t see this as practically a problem. The sorcerer is likely to only get advantage on a few extra rolls out of it, and very unlikely to get advantage on ten bonus action attacks that wouldn’t have had it anyway.
To address your specific questions:

Yes, the advantage applies to every attack made during that minute, so potentially for ten turns (though see my third answer below).
I don’t think the order of operations matters. The save DC and attack rolls are modified, not the spells themselves.
The benefits of Innate Sorcery only last for one minute; when the minute is up, they no longer apply. So if activated before casting storm sphere, they would at most get only nine bonus action attacks that benefitted from it. (And actually, since Innate Sorcery is a Bonus Action, they can’t do both on that first turn in either order, so nine is the maximum either way.)
Yes, it applies to all attack rolls made  during that minute for all Sorcerer spells they cast. There are no other restrictions given. That would include multiple rolls for things like scorching ray, just as the DC would be increased for every creature in the area of effect of a spell which provokes a save.

